# Integral $I_N =\int_0^{\pi}(\frac\pi2 - x)\sin(Nx + \frac x2)\csc\frac x2 dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, trigonometric-integrals

The question from [STEP 2 (1998)](https://www.admissionstesting.org/for-test-takers/step/preparing-for-step/) is as follows:

$$I_N = \int_0^{\pi}\left(\frac\pi2 - x\right)\sin\left(Nx + \frac x2\right)\csc\frac x2 dx.$$

By considering $I_N - I_{N-1}$,  evaluate $I_N$, leaving your answer in the form of a sum.

I have attempted to use compound angle formulae to simplify into something easily integrable but to no avail. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: *Hint*: Use the sum-to-product formula for $\sin(Nx+\frac12x)-\sin((N-1)x+\frac12x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial idea was correct but you just needed to continue. First we have of course
$$ I_n - I_{n-1} = \int_{0}^{\pi} {\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} [\sin(nx+\frac{x}{2})}-\sin((n-1)x+\frac{x}{2})]dx $$

I can now rearrange the terms in the second $\sin$ to give $\sin((nx+\frac{x}{2})-x)$ which can then be expanded by the compound angle formulae to give.

\begin{align} I_n-I_{n-1} &= \int_{0}^{\pi} {\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} [\sin(nx+\frac{x}{2})-\sin(nx+\frac{x}{2})\cos x+\cos(nx+\frac{x}{2})}\sin x] dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\pi} {\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} [(1-\cos x)\sin(nx+\frac{x}{2}) + \cos(nx+\frac{x}{2}) \sin x]dx } \end{align}

Now we use 2 other identities. The half angle and double angle identities for $sin x$. We start with the half angle identity
$$ \sin\frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}} $$
which with rearrangement gives
$$1-\cos x = 2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} $$

And for the double angle identity we have
$$ \sin 2u = 2 \sin u \cos u $$
Now let $x = 2u$, then $u = \frac{x}{2}$, so it follows
$$ \sin x = 2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2} $$

Now using these, substitute for $(1-\cos x)$ and $\sin x$. From there you can cancel the $\sin \frac{x}{2}$. This will give you
$$ I_n-I_{n-1} = \int_{0}^{\pi}(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)[\sin (nx+\frac{x}{2})\sin \frac{x}{2} + \cos(nx+\frac{x}{2})\cos \frac{x}{2}] dx$$

Now these terms can be brought together by the compound angle formula for cos, which results in the integral
$$ I_n-I_{n-1} = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) \cos nx dx $$

Now solve that integral to get $I_n-I_{n-1}$. From there you can calculate $I_0$ easily and then write $I_n$ as a sum the results of $I_0$ and $I_n-I_{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Utilize

$$2\sin\frac x2(\cos x + \cos2x+\cdots+\cos Nx)
= \sin(N+\frac{1}2)x-\sin\frac x2 $$

to integrate

$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^\pi (\frac\pi2-x){\sin(Nx+\frac12x)} \csc \frac x2 dx \\
=&\int_0^\pi (\frac\pi2-x) (1+2\cos x + 2\cos2x+\cdots+2\cos Nx){\rm d}x\\
 \overset{ibp}=& -\frac{\pi^2}2 +\int_0^\pi(x+2\sin x + \frac22\sin2x +\cdots+\frac 2N\sin Nx){d}x\\
=&\bigg(-2 \cos x - \frac24\cos2x - \frac29\cos3x -\cdots -\frac2{N^2}\cos Nx\bigg)\bigg|_0^\pi\\
=&\ 4\bigg(1+\frac19+\frac1{25}+\cdots+\frac1{(2[\frac{N+1}2]-1)^2}\bigg)
\end{align}$$
Note that only the odd terms remain.

Comment: The question is asking for one to consider $I_N-I_{N-1}$